# why JSTL fmt's message tag cannot read properties file?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am a Korean trainee developer. My English is terrible. Please understand that some words and sentences are translated.
I'm using IntelliJ.
When using the "fmt:message" tag, the result will be output to "???" The message output method is being wrapped in fmt:bundle. It is not clear whether the basename property of the bundletag is not readable or simply a problem with the properties file. I attach my project configuration, properties file, JSP file, and output result. If you simply don't know what the problem is, please tell me how to float the error stacks.
Thank you.

MyProject src

[image: MyProject src]

MyProject web

[image: MyProject web]

```
//member.properties
mem.name = \ud64d\uae38\ub3d9
mem.address = \uc11c\uc6b8\uc2dc \uac15\ub0a8\uad6c
mem.job = \ud68c\uacc4\uc0ac
//member_en.properties
mem.name = hong kil-dong
mem.address = kang-name gu, seoul
mem.job = account
//member_ko.properties
mem.name = \ud64d\uae38\ub3d9
mem.address = \uc11c\uc6b8\uc2dc \uac15\ub0a8\uad6c
mem.job = \ud68c\uacc4\uc0ac
```

and jsp code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8"
         isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JSTL Translate</title>
</head>
<body>

<fmt:setLocale value="en_US"/>
<h1>
    User Info<br><br>
    <fmt:bundle basename="resource.member" >
        Name:<fmt:message key="mem.name" /><br>
        Address:<fmt:message key="mem.address" /><br>
        Job:<fmt:message key="mem.job" />
    </fmt:bundle>
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and output result

[image: output result]